# Check if the contents of the x.txt file under a particular directory is the same as the x.txt file content in other directories, bash conditional

Tags: bash, file, directory, conditional-statements, compare

I have tree folders `folder-1`,`folder-2` and `folder-3` located both in my `/home/`.

`folder-1` contains `x.txt`, but `folder-2` contains files `x.txt`, `y.txt`, `z.txt`, etc.

`folder-3` contains contains files `x.txt`, `y.txt`, `z.txt`, etc.

Only `/home/folder-2/x.txt` has the same content as `/home/folder-1/x.txt`.

`/home/folder-2/x.txt` do not have the same content that folder `/home/folder-1/x.txt`.

I know if I want to compare "content" (and not the size or name) of two files in different folders I can use:

```
a="/home/folder-1/x.txt"
b="/home/folder-2/x.txt"

if cmp -s "$a" "$b"; then
    printf 'A file with duplicate content found'
else
    printf 'No file with duplicate content found'
fi
```

But this is not something practical and efficient when I have a single file and your content to compare with files from anothers folders that has many files.

I researched a way to adapt my code write another conditional bash so that I can compare `/home/folder-1/x.txt` with all existing files in `/home/folder-2/{all files}` and `/home/folder-3/{all files}`.

I necessarily need to write this using conditional bash, as if there is a file "x.txt" on the `folder-2` and `folder-3` with the same content that `x.txt` then I will shoot a new command, action or decision.

But so far I have not found anything that can help me concretely.

Note: `folder-2` and `folder-3` has no subdirectories.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a loop that tests each file? `for file in /home/folder-2/*.txt`?

Comment: @Barmar Really, I've already used `loop` for many things but I must have forgotten and maybe for the reason to use it very little with bash. But anyway your answer brought a few things I did not know, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop.

```
file1=/home/folder-1/x.txt
dupfound=
for file2 in /home/folder-2/* /home/folder-3/*
do
    if cmp -s "$file1" "$file2"
    then 
        printf 'Duplicate found: %s\n' "$file2"
        dupfound=true
    fi
done
if [ -z "$dupfound" ]
then "No duplicate found"
fi
```